# Call an asynchronous function with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I write this function in a static class

```
  remove(){
    Keychain
    .resetGenericPassword(Config.keychainGroupe)
    .then(function() {
      AsyncStorage.removeItem('data', (err) => console.log('data deleted, return true', err));
    });
  }
```

I want to asynchronously return true if the data are successfully deleted so I would be able to use the function by calling `await MyClass.remove()`. I tried to return true after removing the item from the  AsyncStorage but I am getting undefined when I call the function with awairt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `Promise` or `async-await`.

The exact way to return the value from `then` method of a promise is as follows

1) Using Promises

```
remove(){

    //Notice return before the Keychain

    return Keychain
        .resetGenericPassword(Config.keychainGroupe)
        .then(function() {
            AsyncStorage.removeItem('data', (err) => console.log('data deleted, return true', err));
            return true;
        });
}
```

or

```
remove(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Keychain
            .resetGenericPassword(Config.keychainGroupe)
            .then(() => {
                AsyncStorage.removeItem('data', (err) => console.log('data deleted, return true', err));
                resolve(true);
            }).catch((err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}
```

2) Using async-await

```
    async remove(){
            try {
              const resolvedData= await Keychain.resetGenericPassword(Config.keychainGroupe)
              if(resolvedData){
                  try {
                      await AsyncStorage.removeItem('data');
                      return true;
                  } catch (err) {
                      console.log('data deleted, return true', err);
                  }
              }
            }
            catch(err) {
                 console.log('Something went wrong with executing resetGenericPassword');
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `return Promise.resolve(true);`. It will wrap the `true` value in a Promise at the next event loop type. For more details about promises, check the [mdn promises documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and/or the [Promises chapter](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20%26%20performance/ch3.md) from the great book series *You don't know JS*

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `async-await`

```
 async remove(){
        try {
          const data = await Keychain.resetGenericPassword(Config.keychainGroupe)
          try {
            await AsyncStorage.removeItem('data');
            return true;
          } catch (error) {
              return false
          }
        }
        catch(error) {
             console.log('keychain method failed')
        }
    }
```